# Issue with title bootbox

Tags: javascript, bootbox

Can anyone tell me how to fix it? Ihave the same title issue in the alert box.

```
bootbox.confirm({
    title: "Confirmation",
    message: "Are you sure you want to delete the selected items?",
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
             label: 'Yes',
             className: 'btn-success',
        },
        cancel: {
            label: 'No',
            className: 'btn-danger'
        }
    },
    callback: function (result) {
                    if (result == true) {
                        $("#delete").submit();
                    } 
                }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Alignment issue? Why dont you do inspect element and see what styles are applied on it.

Comment: Close (x) element is created before the title. How to change the order of creation elements wthout changing the library code?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is because of `float` CSS property. You have `float: right;` on your title.

Comment: When i set  `.modal-title {  float: none }` nothing has changed.

Comment: This happens when you use Bootbox 4.x with Bootstrap 4 - it's built for Bootstrap 3. If you want built-in Bootstrap 4 support, use the [5.x branch](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/tree/v5.x), or make the changes noted [here](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/issues/566).

Comment: @TiesonT. Thanks - I added a bootbox5.js file and copied the code from the 5.x beta branch and now it works until 5 is released.

Comment: Okay. Just so you're aware, there are a few new options (see https://tiesont.github.io/bootbox/documentation.html#prompt-options and https://tiesont.github.io/bootbox/documentation.html#bb-options), and every locale except 'en' has been pulled into a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have messed up some CSS.

Maybe you are using another library which is overwriting bootbox styles.

You can try the following to fix that particular issue:

```
.bootbox .modal-header h4 {
  float: none;
}

.bootbox .modal-header .close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: It did not help.

Comment: Did it change something ... Can we see it anywhere?

Comment: No, nothing has changed. 
Unfortunately, I can not make this code public.

Comment: Did not help. Only when I remove x the title is in the right place

Comment: Then add a `float: right !important;` to the button.close element. Be aware that the use of important is bad practice..

Comment: I did not help too.

Comment: Maybe it's not the most elegant solution but it works. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed... I got good exp with using scss and wrapping css imports in classes to scope them. To avoid them overwriting each other...

Answer (score 0):

It is a version problem. 
If you are using boot-box v4.x then you need Bootstrap v5.x

So check with the version.
[image]

If you cannot make the version compatible, Please follow the below code:

```
closeButton = $('.bootbox').find('.bootbox-close-button');
$('.bootbox').find('.modal-header').append(closeButton);
```

It rearranges the close button properly.